# Choosing between jdbcTemplate.update(String sql,Object[] args,int[] argTypes) and jdbcTemplate.update(String sql,Object[] args)

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I'm learning the combination of Spring Boot and jdbcTemplate for some basic crud operations, and trying to better understand which update method I should choose.

I understand that the following two class approaches (adapted from [this post](https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-insert-a-new-record-into-a-database-using-jdbctemplate/)) will write the same record to the database.

Example 1:

```
public class InsertDemo {
private static final String sql =
        "INSERT INTO records (title, " +
        "    release_date, " +
        "    artist_id, " +
        "    label_id, " +
        "    created) " +
        "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

private DataSource dataSource;

public InsertDemo(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

public void saveRecord(String title, Date releaseDate,
                       Integer artistId, Integer labelId) {
    JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(this.dataSource);

    Object[] params = new Object[] {
            title, releaseDate, artistId, labelId, new Date()
    };
    int[] types = new int[] {
            Types.VARCHAR,
            Types.DATE,
            Types.INTEGER,
            Types.INTEGER,
            Types.DATE
    };

    int row = template.update(sql, params, types);
    System.out.println(row + " row inserted.");
}
```

Example 2:

```
public class InsertDemo {
private static final String sql =
        "INSERT INTO records (title, " +
        "    release_date, " +
        "    artist_id, " +
        "    label_id, " +
        "    created) " +
        "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

private DataSource dataSource;

public InsertDemo(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

public void saveRecord(String title, Date releaseDate,
                       Integer artistId, Integer labelId) {
    JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(this.dataSource);

    Object[] params = new Object[] {
            title, releaseDate, artistId, labelId, new Date()
    };

    int row = template.update(sql, params);
    System.out.println(row + " row inserted.");
}
```

but I'm unclear on why I would/should use the first one that specifies argument types.  I've read [the javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-int:A-) but I'm still not sure why I would need to specify the types.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting argument type provides correctness and optimisation (slight) for the underlying SQL statement. (The `JdbcTemplate` internally builds a `PreparedStatement` and sets values to it using provided/derived types).

In your example, if you don't specify `Types` array, they will be set as `SqlTypeValue.TYPE_UNKOWN` which eventually be guessed or resolved as;

```
if (sqlType == SqlTypeValue.TYPE_UNKNOWN || sqlType == Types.OTHER) {
            if (isStringValue(inValue.getClass())) {
                ps.setString(paramIndex, inValue.toString());
            }
            else if (isDateValue(inValue.getClass())) {
                ps.setTimestamp(paramIndex, new java.sql.Timestamp(((java.util.Date) inValue).getTime()));
            }
            else if (inValue instanceof Calendar) {
                Calendar cal = (Calendar) inValue;
                ps.setTimestamp(paramIndex, new java.sql.Timestamp(cal.getTime().getTime()), cal);
            }
            else {
                // Fall back to generic setObject call without SQL type specified.
                ps.setObject(paramIndex, inValue);
            }
        }
```

Have a look at `org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils#setValue`

So it's a good practice to set the arg types.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Comment: Do you know what is integer code of type? E.g., which code should I choose for integer or varchar or text? PS: seems I found it in `java.sql.Types`

Answer (score 1):

Without `Type` parameter:

> sql SQL containing bind parameters args arguments to bind to the query
>   (leaving it to the PreparedStatement to guess the corresponding SQL
>   type); may also contain SqlParameterValue objects which indicate not
>   only the argument value but also the SQL type and optionally the scale

With `Type` parameter:

> sql SQL containing bind parameters args arguments to bind to the query
>   argTypes SQL types of the arguments (constants from java.sql.Types)

Comment: Is it possible you transposed the "with" and "without" in this answer? The first one says "with", but then states "leaving it to the PreparedStatement to guess the corresponding SQL type", but per @Laksitha-Ranasingha answer above, it seems that the _without_ is what would leave it up to the guesswork mentioned.